# Android: GridView scroll trouble

Tags: android, gridview

I have **GridView 4x25**, which contains **RadioButton & TextView** in every cell. TextView takes the **index of cell**, so my Grid looks like this:

```
o1  o2  o3  o4
o5  o6  o7  o8
...
o97 o98 o99 o100
```

**My Adapter**:

```
public class FieldAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context; TextView Cell_num; int index = 0;

  public FieldAdapter(Context context) 
     {
                    this.context=context;

     }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  public int getCount() 
  {
               return 100;
  }

     public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {                            
             if (convertView == null) 
             {
                     LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
                     index++;                                                
             }
             Log.d("Cell","Created");
             Cell_num = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_cell_text);
             Cell_num.setText(Integer.toString(index));
      return convertView;
     }
```

}

It's works good, and i have **100** messages in my **LogCat** for every cell.

> Log.d("Cell","Created");

**But**, if I will **scroll down GridView**, this messages will continue to appear - 4 mesagges for 4 cells hiding behind the top edge of the screen.

If I scroll back my GridView and see those cells, that were hidden, all TextViews take value **"28"**, not index of cells. So, **after scrolling**, I see this picture:

```
o28  o28  o28  o28
o28  o28  o28  o28
...
o28  o28  o28  o28
```

**Furthermore**, if I check some RadioButton before scrolling, it will change it's position after each hidding/emersion from top edge of the screen.

In my mind it is some kind of magic =(

Need help.

## UPDATE

Problem still here. I changed my adapter:

```
public class FieldAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context; TextView Cell_num;
LayoutInflater inflater;

  public FieldAdapter(Context context) 
     {
                    this.context=context;
                    inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

     }

// id по позиции
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

// элемент по позиции
  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  public int getCount() 
  {
               return 100;
  }

  @Override
     public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {                            
             if (convertView == null) 
             {
                     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
                     Cell_num = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_cell_text);
                     Cell_num.setText(Integer.toString(pos));
                     Log.d("Filled cell number",Integer.toString(pos));
             }
      return convertView;
     }
}
```

My LogCat (with my comments):

```
05-07 11:44:32.151: D/States(15888): Button pressed
05-07 11:44:33.603: D/States(15888): Button pressed
05-07 11:44:33.603: D/States(15888): Activity2: onPause()
/* Start filling cells*/
05-07 11:44:33.653: D/Filled cell number(15888): 0
05-07 11:44:33.673: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(15888): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-07 11:44:33.683: D/Filled cell number(15888): 1
05-07 11:44:33.683: D/Filled cell number(15888): 2
05-07 11:44:33.693: D/Filled cell number(15888): 3
05-07 11:44:33.693: D/Filled cell number(15888): 4
05-07 11:44:33.703: D/Filled cell number(15888): 5
05-07 11:44:33.703: D/Filled cell number(15888): 6
05-07 11:44:33.703: D/Filled cell number(15888): 7
05-07 11:44:33.713: D/Filled cell number(15888): 8
05-07 11:44:33.713: D/Filled cell number(15888): 9
05-07 11:44:33.713: D/Filled cell number(15888): 10
05-07 11:44:33.723: D/Filled cell number(15888): 11
05-07 11:44:33.723: D/Filled cell number(15888): 12
05-07 11:44:33.733: D/Filled cell number(15888): 13
05-07 11:44:33.733: D/Filled cell number(15888): 14
05-07 11:44:33.743: D/Filled cell number(15888): 15
05-07 11:44:33.743: D/Filled cell number(15888): 16
05-07 11:44:33.743: D/Filled cell number(15888): 17
05-07 11:44:33.753: D/Filled cell number(15888): 18
05-07 11:44:33.753: D/Filled cell number(15888): 19
05-07 11:44:33.763: D/Filled cell number(15888): 20
05-07 11:44:33.763: D/Filled cell number(15888): 21
05-07 11:44:33.763: D/Filled cell number(15888): 22
05-07 11:44:33.773: D/Filled cell number(15888): 23
/*Stops filling cells*/
05-07 11:44:33.783: D/Filled cell number(15888): 0   /*Starts again? Why only 1 cell with 0 index?*/
05-07 11:44:34.033: D/States(15888): Activity2: onStop()
05-07 11:44:34.033: D/States(15888): Activity2: onDestroy()
/* AFTER SCROLLING*/
05-07 11:44:55.376: D/Filled cell number(15888): 25
05-07 11:44:55.376: D/Filled cell number(15888): 26
05-07 11:44:55.386: D/Filled cell number(15888): 27  /*Why only 25 26 27 ? */
```

It is  only 27 cells creating in a circle with randomly changing its position on Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how adapters work.  getView will always be called anytime a row comes into view.  That's why getView has the `int position` parameter.  Use that instead of `index++`.

```
Cell_num.setText(Integer.toString(pos));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are declaring your layout inflate each time when row view is begin created.so its better to declare your Layout inflate in the constructor itself.
Like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
public FieldAdapter(Context context) 
  {
            this.context=context;
  inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

 }
```

So when view Inflate is declared each time there is a possibility of change in the data while scrolling the views and as

> user1199931 said you dont want to add your index by index++ because
>   in the **get view methord** you will get the row position of your cell.The enter
>   code after changing is like this

,

```
 public class FieldAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context; TextView Cell_num; int index = 0;
LayoutInflater inflater;
  public FieldAdapter(Context context) 
 {
                this.context=context;
  inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

 }

@Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
}

 public Object getItem(int position) {
return 0;
 }

public int getCount() 
{
           return 100;
}

 public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {                            
         if (convertView == null) 
         {

                 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
                // index++;  as  user1199931 said your need not want an increment section here                                             
         }
         Log.d("Cell","Created");
         Cell_num = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_cell_text);
         Cell_num.setText(Integer.toString(pos));
  return convertView;
 }

}
```

Hope this will help you ,Thank you

Comment: Not helps. See my post after UPDATE header.